# Getting process instance name from a process id / object (Faster way)

Tags: c#

Currently, the solution to get a Instance Name from a Process ID is from the code below. 
Problem is, this takes a lot of time and CPU resources!

That is to say when you have a system that's running at least 100 processes, it takes a considerable amount of time to cycle through the loops to find it. (like 1 to 2 seconds) And when I am looking to find up to 30 of those processes, it takes up to 30 seconds to find them all...

Can't you simply get a instance name from a process object?

```
private static string GetProcessInstanceName(int pid)
{
  PerformanceCounterCategory cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process");

  string[] instances = cat.GetInstanceNames();
  foreach (string instance in instances)
  {

     using (PerformanceCounter cnt = new PerformanceCounter("Process",  
          "ID Process", instance, true))
     {
        int val = (int) cnt.RawValue;
        if (val == pid)
        {
           return instance;
        }
     }
  }
  throw new Exception("Could not find performance counter " + 
      "instance name for current process. This is truly strange ...");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById` function?

```
private static string GetProcessInstanceName(int pid)
{ 
    string name = String.Empty;
    Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(pid);
    if(proc != null)
    {
        name = proc.ProcessName;
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is, if there multiple instances of the same nname, eg: java#1 java#2, it doesn't return the correct process number.. only just java.

Comment: @user3289302 You can't get more specific than a `process id`. If you got it, it will most certainly return the 1 (and only) process with that pid.

Comment: The PerformanceCounter method requires a instanceName instead of a PID...like here: new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", instanceName);   your function above will work fine if there was only 1 instance of the same name running, but when you have 2 of the same instance names your method doesn't return it like the way performanceCounter is expecting it.. eg java#1 java#2 would you know any other way? or maybe is there a way to feed PerformanceCounter with pid instead?

Comment: @@user3289302 Did I get your question wrong? If so, My apologies. It seems by the name of your function (`GetProcessInstanceName`) and by the logics implemented in the function that you are attempting to get the a process name by it's Id. If I am correct, You can use my function rather than yours, and `PerformanceCounter` is not required.

Answer (score 2):

The [FranzHuber23 Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39394606/240845) sped the original by only looking at processes that start with the process-in-question's name. An improvement beyond that uses PLINQ (parallel LINQ). Optionally, `Parallel.ForEach()` or a construct that uses `Task` could provide a similar speedup but both those will have complicated source to return just the first found and cancel the concurrent searches (nicely hidden by `ParallelEnumerable.FirstOrDefault()`).

```
public static string PerformanceCounterInstanceName(this Process process)
{
    var matchesProcessId = new Func<string, bool>(instanceName =>
    {
        using (var pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", instanceName, true))
        {
            if ((int)pc.RawValue == process.Id)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    });

    string processName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(process.ProcessName);
    return new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process")
       .GetInstanceNames()
       .AsParallel()
       .FirstOrDefault(instanceName => instanceName.StartsWith(processName)
                                       && matchesProcessId(instanceName));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very fast and well-working solution is this one:

```
public static string GetInstanceNameForProcessId(int processId)
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        string processName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(process.ProcessName);

        PerformanceCounterCategory cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process");
        string[] instances = cat.GetInstanceNames()
            .Where(inst => inst.StartsWith(processName))
            .ToArray();

        foreach (string instance in instances)
        {
            using (PerformanceCounter cnt = new PerformanceCounter("Process",
                "ID Process", instance, true))
            {
                int val = (int)cnt.RawValue;
                if (val == processId)
                {
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

from [Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Sep/27/Capturing-Performance-Counter-Data-for-a-Process-by-Process-Id). The only issue I had was the same as one in the commentaries on his blog:

> One thing to mention related to windows process instance 
>   names is that they change dynamically when one of the processes exits.
>
> For example if chrome#8 exits, chrome#9 will become chrome#8 and
>   chrome#10
>
> will become chrome#9. At this point getting the value of the counter
>   previously created for chrome#10 will throw an exception. This is
>   really annoying if you want to to monitor multiple instances of
>   multiple processes as it gets down to monitoring process exits and
>   recreating all the counters (really ugly).
>
> One way would be to change the way process instance names are
>   generated (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281884) but this has
>   the potential of affecting other apps using the perfmon api.

Answer (score -1):

This should get you all of the current processes

```
var allProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
```

you can then iterate through the array to find the specific id's you are looking for